# How to pass `boost::static_visitor` instances to functions

Tags: c++, templates, boost, visitor-pattern, boost-variant

I'm using `boost::variant` quite often in my projects. My colleagues now came up with the idea to pass around instances of specific `boost::static_visitor<int>` in order to customize the type of visitation. She had some code like the following:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::variant<int, std::string> TVar;

struct Visitor1 : public boost::static_visitor<int> {
    template<typename T> 
    result_type operator()(const T&) {
        return 42;
    }
};

struct Visitor2 : public boost::static_visitor<int> {
    template<typename T>
    result_type operator()(const T&) {
        return 21;
    }
};

 int adder(const boost::static_visitor<int>& visitor, const TVar& visitable) {
     return visitable.apply_visitor(visitor) + 1;
 }

int main(int argc, char **args) {
    Visitor1 v1;
    Visitor2 v2;
    TVar x;

    std::cout << adder(v1, x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << adder(v2, x) << std::endl;
}
```

It looks perfectly sound to me, but it doesn't compile. My compiler says that `expression will not yield a function that takes one 1 argument` somewhere insider .

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should mark your visitors' `operator()` overloads as `const`:

```
struct Visitor1 : public boost::static_visitor<int> {
    template<typename T> 
    result_type operator()(const T&) const {
        return 42;
    }
};

struct Visitor2 : public boost::static_visitor<int> {
    template<typename T>
    result_type operator()(const T&) const {
        return 21;
    }
};
```

Then, you need to change your adder to accept a template parameter instead of `boost::static_visitor` - it is your `Visitor1` type that contains the `operator()` overload with the logic you desire. You need the "correct type" for the visitation to take place.

```
template <typename T>
int adder(const T& visitor, const TVar& visitable) {
    return visitable.apply_visitor(visitor) + 1;
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZPrsw2QlZUh6AUPB)

Comment: Ouch! So obvious. Thanks for the help. I really cannot get used to this templates.

Answer (score 4):

There's an overload for `apply_visitor` that takes only the visitor. This returns a partially applied function object that suits your needs, I guess:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant/reference.html#header.boost.variant.apply_visitor_hpp

This overload returns a

> [Class template apply_visitor_delayed_t
>   boost::apply_visitor_delayed_t — Adapts a visitor for use as a function object.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost/apply_visitor_delayed_t.html)

Personally, I like to add an overload to the visitor object like this:

```
struct MyVisitor {
    typedef void result_type;

    template <typename... Ts>
    result_type operator()(boost::variant<Ts...> const& v) const {
         return boost::apply_visitor(*this, v);
    }
    // optionally repeat for non-const `v`

    // normal variant handling overloads
};
```

That way, you can simply use the visitor object as the function oject.

Comment: Very interesting. I was not even aware of this call. But still I'm unsure how to use it. Assume I have `auto y=boost::apply_visitor(v1)`. How can I pass `y ` to my `adder` function?

Comment: You pass it like you would anywhere you pass a calleable object (either deduce the argument type with template type argument or erase that type using `std::function<>` or similar)

Comment: Many thanks. I think that Angew already showed my how to do it. :-)

Comment: Indeed. That's part of his approach as well

Answer (score 3):

`static_visitor` is not a polymorphic base class, and cannot be treated as such. It's in the very name: it's a **static** (statically typed) visitor. You need the *static* type of the visitor to be the one you want to invoke. Note that this is unavoidable, because member function templates cannot be virtual. In your case, this means `adder` will have to become a function template, templated by the visitor type:

```
template <class Visitor>
int adder(const Visitor& visitor, const TVar& visitable) {
  return visitable.apply_visitor(visitor) + 1;
}
```

Use in `main` will then remain the same.

If you cannot afford to make `adder` a template, you can use `apply_visitor` mentioned by [@sehe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43676822/1782465) in combination with `std::function` (or `boost::function` if you cannot use C++11):

```
int adder(std::function<int(const TVar&)> visitorApplier, const TVar& visitable)
{
  return visitorApplier(visitable);
}

int main(int argc, char **args) {
    Visitor1 v1;
    Visitor2 v2;
    TVar x;

    std::cout << adder(boost::apply_visitor(v1), x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << adder(boost::apply_visitor(v2), x) << std::endl;
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cb5c79ff2ace8d0)

Technically, the visitor itself is an appropriate callable object already, so it should work even without explicit use of `apply_visitor`:

```
int main(int argc, char **args) {
    Visitor1 v1;
    Visitor2 v2;
    TVar x;

    std::cout << adder(v1, x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << adder(v2, x) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a very cool solution. Unfortunately, it is not compiling. Do I have a problem with my visual studio compiler? It should support C++11.

Comment: It says that converting from `boost::apply_visitor_delayed_t<Visitor1>` to `const std::function<int (void)> &` is not possible. I made the passed variable `visitorApplier` a const reference.

Comment: Just found out, that you can replace `adder(boost::apply_visitor(v1), x)` by `adder(v1, x)`. So you can even shorten your solution.